# Unrecognized Date format

Tags: php, javascript, date, date-format

Good  !

I am having some difficulties with extracting data from a date. The thing is that I get a  number from an undocumented API.

> "created": 734394 
>   "last_chapter_date": 734883

I tried dividing it by 365,242 days (exact amount of days a year)

> 2010,705231052289 
>   So apparently these are the number of days passed since 0.0.0000

I am currently trying something like that:
 http://jsfiddle.net/LRUy5/4/

```
function zero21970(nDays) {
    // 0     70   2013  
    // |-----|-----|  

    // 0 to date
    var dateMils = nDays*24*60*60*100;
    // 0 to 1970
    zeroTo1970 = (1970*365.242)*24*60*60*100;

    //subtract time from 0-1970 from the time 0-date
    //to cut out the part from 1970-today
    return new Date(dateMils-zeroTo1970);
}

//http://www.mangaeden.com/api/manga/4e70e9f6c092255ef7004344/
zero21970(734394) //-> Jan 26 1974
```

I need to save it in a database and work with it via php or javascript..
Does anyone recognize this kind of format or do you know a convenient way of formatting it?

Edit: I should add that the last chapter came out around 15.01.2013.. just to have something to grab.

Comment: Just dividing by the average number of days in a year won't be good enough. Recall that since Jan 01, 0000 the calendars of various peoples have changed, so some of the years between then and now had less (or more) than 365 days in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated version:

I guess if the last chapter was from 2013, then the value is a number of days from `01.01.0001`. So we can update the initial date as well as change `setHours` to `setDate` method for more accuracy:

```
var date = new Date("0001");
date.setDate(734883);
date.toGMTString();  // "Tue, 15 Jan 2013 00:00:00 GMT"
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LRUy5/6/

---

**Old version:**

I found one solution that successfully works at my computer:

```
var date = new Date("0000");
date.setHours(734394 * 24);
date.toGMTString();  // "Mon, 13 Sep 2010 21:00:00 GMT"
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LRUy5/5/

Comment: Is '0000' a valid ISO8601 or RFC2822 date?  ('wondering how x-platform this is)

Comment: @broofa It should be so :) However I'm a bit confused in using `setHours` or `setDate`: it give a bit different results.

Comment: I don't understand how the two answers could be so different.

Comment: @Pointy I used different dates for tests: `734883` vs `734394`.

Comment: Oh durr :-) well that explains it

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I can confirm that it is returning correct dates. Then the only thing that's left is to figure out a way to implement this in php ;) But thats for tomorrow! Thanks, you safed me there :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP, then you should replace

```
return new Date(dateMils-zeroTo1970);
```

with

```
return date('Y-m-d', (dateMils-zeroTo1970));
```